# I cant get lastInsertId on laravel 7 project

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder, last-insert-id

```
$sql = DB::table('laravel_products')
    ->insert(array(
        'name' => $name,
        'price' => $price,
        'qty' => $qty,
        'description' => $description,
        'uruu' => $uruu,
        'garage' => $garage,
        'duureg' => $duureg,
        'tagt' => $tagt,
        'talbai' => $talbai,
        'haalga' => $haalga,
        'tsonh' => $tsonh,
        'shal' => $shal,
        'tsonhtoo' => $ttsonh,
        'hdawhar' => $bdawhar,
        'lizing' => $lizing,
        'utas' => $utas,
        'email' => $email,
        'hereg' => $hereg,
        'bairshil' => $bairshil,
        'bairlal' => $bairlal,
        'ashig' => $ashigon,
        'zahi' => $zahi,
        'image' => $data
    ));

$lastInsertedID = $sql->lastInsertId();
```

When I try to insert its responses:

> "Call to a member function lastInsertId() on bool"

I used `insertGetId` but its cant save multiple rows of pictures on mysql.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... the `insert` method doesn't return an object you could call methods on, it returns a `bool` .., you could get the underlying PDO instance from the connection and call that method on it though: `DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId()`

Comment: Thanks, its gets id and the product tables id and images tables ids are same now but looks not linked is it okay ?

Comment: idk what you mean by linked, you are inserting a single record into one table here

Comment: now i edited main post and thanks for helping me ^^ here is the pictures and codes

Comment: what is the issue with the new part there?

Comment: so tried to add multiple images to mysql but its saves first image that i chosen so tried on php its works fine but not laravel

Comment: uploaded files would have to be moved to a permanent location then you could get that path and store in the database, but that is outside the scope of this question .... is there a problem with the loop inserting records in the database?

Comment: i think i cant use SO properly sorry should i post another questions ?

Comment: it depends what you are trying to ask about now ... in reality your original question is answered and solved, but you seem to have more database issues to work on

Comment: and thanks for helping me ^^

Comment: I am going to revert your question to the original version and you can create a new question about any further questions, about image upload or the next set of database queries, etc ... good luck

Comment: please feel free to accept an answer if they helped you out

Comment: done ^^ i didnt know it accepts answer thanks ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the last inserted ID like that you can call that method on the `PDO` instance directly:

```
$id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
```

Answer (score 1):

If the table has an auto-incrementing id, use the insertGetId method to insert a record and then retrieve the ID:

```
$id = DB::table('users')->insertGetId(
    ['email' => 'john@example.com', 'votes' => 0]
);
```

from : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#inserts

Answer (score 0):

```
        $data = new LaravelProducts(); //LaravelProducts is your Model Name
    
        $data->name= $name; //here 'name' is your column name
        $data->price= $price; //here 'price' is your column name
        $data->qty= $qty; //here 'qty' is your column name
        $data->description= $description; //here 'description' is your column name
        ..........
        ..........
        $data->image= $image; //here 'image' is your column name

        $data->save();
        
        $lastInsertedId = $data->id;
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to write a new query to collect last inserted id from database.

```
$laravel_product = DB::table('laravel_products')
             ->insertGetId( array(
                 'name' => $name,
                 'price' => $price,
                 'qty' => $qty,
                 'description' => $description,
                 'uruu' => $uruu,
                 'garage' => $garage,
                 'duureg' => $duureg,
                 'tagt' => $tagt,
                 'talbai' => $talbai,
                 'haalga' => $haalga,
                 'tsonh' => $tsonh,
                 'shal' => $shal,
                 'tsonhtoo' => $ttsonh,
                 'hdawhar' => $bdawhar,
                 'lizing' => $lizing,
                 'utas' => $utas,
                 'email' => $email,
                 'hereg' => $hereg,
                 'bairshil' => $bairshil,
                 'bairlal' => $bairlal,
                 'ashig' => $ashigon,
                 'zahi' => $zahi,
                 'image' => $data
                 )
             );

  foreach ($filenamesToSave as $filename) {
            DB::insert('INSERT INTO laravel_products_images ( product_id, filename ) VALUES ( ?, ? )',[$laravel_product->id, $filename]);
            return view('createproduct');
        } // Foreach Closing

 // Echo your inserted ID Like Below
 echo $laravel_product->id;
```

It should be 100% working for you.

Comment: no ... `insert` returns a `bool` https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L2885

Comment: `insertGetId` returns an 'id' (int) not an object